# Chrome DevTools и PHPStorm

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, phpstorm, google-chrome-devtools

Привет друзья! Раньше пользовался Sublime и расширением LiveReload, что позволяло вносить правки в HTML/CSS файлы как со стороны редактора, так и со стороны DevTools с последующим обновлением кода/отображения в браузере.

Для PHPStorm такого решения не нашел. Установил только LiveEdit который позволяет вносить правки в IDE и наблюдать их реализацию в браузере. Хотелось бы двустороннюю связь - редактирую в DevTools -> наблюдаю изменения в IDE.

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью каких инструментов можно реализовать данный функционал!

PS использование Chrome не принципиально, могу пользоваться Firebug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для PHPStorm единого решения не существует, к сожалению:( **Live edit** поддерживает синхронизацию из редактора в Chrome; плагин [CSS-X-Fire](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5348-css-x-fire) дает возможность редактировать код в Firefox и видеть изменения в редакторе.

Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-8814](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8814) и [WEB-9557](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9557) - это запросы на двустороннюю синхронизацию